# Batch File to delete contents of folder not modified in the last 3 days?

Tags: windows-server-2008, batch-file

Anyone know of a script which I can execute with task scheduler which will allow me to delete the contents of a specified folder, but only the content that hasn't been modified for the last 3 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in a powershell script which is supported in windows server 2008. I found this at stackoverflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827738/powershell-script-to-delete-old-files